# Call a method annotated with @valid and that has an Errors argument

Tags: java, spring

I've written a method that validates some tasks, but it requires an object annotated with @valid and an Errors argument. This is the method definition:

```
 public T validate(PasswordEncoder encoder , @Valid T user , Errors errors)
    {
        this.statusMsg = (Map<String , String>) errors.getAllErrors().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(ObjectError::getObjectName , ObjectError::getDefaultMessage));

        out.println(statusMsg);

//        TODO : test that user if it a enterpriseContainer or UserContainer .
        if(user.getClass() == EnterpriseContainer.class)
        {

        }
        else if(user.getClass() == UserContainer.class)
        {

        }

//        TODO : encode the passwd and test it with the confirmation one .

        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that i want to call it manually, so i have to insert an Errors object, which has no error, inside the method where I test the Errors' object's fields .
Is there any way to tell the compiler that the Errors object must be obtained from the @valid T user result ? ???

Comment: Please show the implementation of this method?

Comment: i've modified my question to fit your desire sir .